# How to upload a list of file to firebase storage from firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that will take a request from frontend with a file's name, which will be a video that stored in firebase storage, and then I will apply ffmpeg and extract the video to many frames. In the end, I will upload all frames into firebase storage.
Everything works good, I am able to get all frames. However, there is a problem with uploading frames. Sometimes I can upload all frames successfully, but the function will keep running until timeout, and sometimes I can only upload the first frame. I am new to node.js. I guess there is a problem with return or promise (I don't quit understand what to return and how to handle promise).
Also, I would like to write the data of each frame to database. Where should I put this part of code?

```
exports.extractFrame = functions.https.onRequest(function (req, res) {

const name = req.query.fileName;
const username = name.substr(0, name.length - 4);
const sessionId = 'video-org';
const framePath = 'frame-org';

const sourceBucketName = 'this is my bucket name';
const sourceBucket = gcs.bucket(sourceBucketName);
const temDir = os.tmpdir();

return sourceBucket.file(sessionId + '/' + name).download({
    destination: temDir + '/' + name
  }
).then(() => {
  console.log('extract frames');
  return spawn(ffmpegPath, ['-i', temDir + '/' + name, temDir + '/' + 
username + '%d.png']);
}).then(() => {
  const frames = fs.readdirSync(temDir);
  console.log(frames);

for (let index in frames) {
  if (index != 0) {
    console.log('uploading');
    sourceBucket.upload(temDir + '/' + frames[index], {destination: 
framePath + '/' + frames[index]});
  }
}
}).then(() => {
res.send('I am done');
});
});
```

Thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Collect all the promises from all of the calls to `sourceBucket.upload()` into an array, then use Promise.all() to wait for the entire set to resolve before sending the response:

```
const promises = [];
for (let index in frames) {
  if (index != 0) {
    console.log('uploading');
    const p = sourceBucket.upload(temDir + '/' + frames[index], {destination: 
framePath + '/' + frames[index]});
    promises.push(p);
  }
}
return Promise.all(promises);
```

Also, you don't return a promise from an HTTP type function.  Just sending the response with `res.send()` will end the function.  This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

Comment: In this case, do I still need to return the download promise and spawn? Thank you

Comment: You need to chain the promises as you are now in order to make the next step wait for the previous step, but returning the top level promise from the function won't help anything in an HTTP function.

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a gist](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/d4f1327b58ad69334ef06327184df790) on this a while back:

```
// set it up
firebase.storage().ref().constructor.prototype.putFiles = function(files) { 
  var ref = this;
  return Promise.all(files.map(function(file) {
    return ref.child(file.name).put(file);
  }));
}

// use it!
firebase.storage().ref().putFiles(files).then(function(metadatas) {
  // Get an array of file metadata
}).catch(function(error) {
  // If any task fails, handle this
});
```